# AWS Lambda function Billed duration includes Init Duration as well when using Lambda container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, billing

This is what I see in my AWS Cloudwatch logs:

```
REPORT RequestId: aaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-yyyy-xxxxxxxx    Duration: 3322.91 ms    
Billed Duration: 9995 ms    Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 137 MB 
Init Duration: 6671.44 ms
```

My question is, why does `Billed Duration` include `Init duration` as well ?

Billed Duration (9995 ms) = Init Duration(6671.44ms) + Duration(3322.91ms)

I'm using a Lambda container which is based on the aws provided lambda python:3.8 lambda container. Is the Init Duration being included in Billed Duration because I'm using my own container ?

Below is the Dockerfile on which the container is based on:

```sh
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt /var/task
RUN pip3 install -r /var/task/requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["handler/run"]
```

Less relevant info:

In the container, I'm hitting an api, parsing the results and uploading to dynamodb.

Comment: In my case, the Duration is not a total of Billed Duration and Init Duration. Confused. This is contradictory to what is being said in this post. Can someone from AWS help so we can understand how to interpret these metrics.

REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Duration: 1379.53 ms Billed Duration: 1380 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 82 MB Init Duration: 599.03 ms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at Lambda pricing details documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) - you will see a small asterick (*)  :-) mentioning below

> Duration charges apply to code that runs in the handler of a function
> as well as **initialization** code that is declared outside of the
> handler.

So yes the initialization code (`init`) is also considered in billing as well.
As you can see from the Lambda execution model [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html) , everything before handler invoke is considered to be part of `init` phase.

Comment: @Shailedra, thanks for the reply. I just cross-checked by running the container the second time, it got billed only for the 'duration' of function invocation and not initialization as it was probably still warm!

Comment: @Gru Yes it's because it is still warmed up. There is a feature of "Provisioned Concurrency" provided by AWS which allows you to prepare execution environments before receiving traffic and thereby getting rid of high init times.